# Encoding YUV Color Space with Positive Numbers

Tags: image-processing, image-compression, color

I got 2 hdr rgb textures/signals. When fetched one gets bicubicly interpolated and the other bilinearly. So I was thinking I can store as YUV and store Y from each texture in the bicubic one and the distribution of the rest of the channels are not as important.

Well another restriction is that the hdr output only accept pos float values.

So what I'm wondering are there some other colour space transform similar to standard YUV but which range is positive only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use YUV with a shift?

To make my example simpler, let's use the [Color Space YCoCg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCoCg).
So the channels `Co, Cg` are in the range `[-0.5, 0.5]`.

When you encode them, make sure you encode `Co', Cg'` where `Co' = Co + 0.5` and `Cg' = cG + 0.5`.

Comment: I could do that. However the original input is hdr, i.e. unbound and goes above 1. So in that case I would need to come up with some max offset and saturate in case U or V goes negative. I was mainly looking for if there's a more elegant solution, preferably without arbitrary limits :)

Comment: Do you have the Sensor Data? As even in HDR sensor the data is in some data class (`UINT32`) hence you can easily infer the maximum required offset.